# How do i make a button show a new page and add a specified text of the textview in the new page?

Tags: android

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TextView tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView);
            String myText = "this is the text";
            // note this textview is in the Newactivity layout. A null pointer exception is thrown here
            tView.setText(myText);
            //this moves theactivity1 intent to the NewActivity intent. It works        
            Intent newActIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),NewActivity.class);
            startActivity(newActIntent);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Just pass an Extra value through your intent then extract it in your second activity and set the value of the text view

Comment: Please edit your code to make it readable. Format the indentation of you code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should pass the string value to the NewActivity by using

`newActIntent.putExtra("someKey", myText);` in your first Activity.

Your onClick method should be something like this:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

        String myText = "this is the text";
        Intent newActIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),NewActivity.class);
        newActIntent.putExtra("someKey", myText);
        startActivity(newActIntent);
}
```

Then on your NewActivity you should retrieve the `someKey`value you stored in the first activity and use the extracted value to set the TextView text:

```
String textValue = intent.getExtras().getString("someKey");
TextView tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView);
tView.setText(textValue);
```

The reason why you're getting the NullPointerException when trying to set the text in your first activity is because `findViewById(id)`will try to find a view with the specified ID in the layout of your current Activity, not on every Activity you have. For this reason you should first start the Activity where the TextView is declared, retrieve the TextView by using the `findViewById(id)`method and then set the text, based on the value you passed using the Intent.

Comment: Thanks.i am now getting it clear. but i am receiving a nullpointer on String textValue = intent.getExtras().getString("name");

Comment: I assumed you are saving the intent to a variable by using the getIntent() method. In your onCreate method you should have something like Intent intent = getIntent() and then call the getExtras()

Comment: Can you explain the -1? My answer was the same as the chosen answer...

Answer (score -1):

You cannot access a view if you haven't set the layout it belongs first. You will set the content of the textview when the NewActivity is created.

To achieve that, you will give an Extra String parameter to the intent which starts your new activity.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.your_layout); // this has to be called before accessing views 
     Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

     btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
         Intent newActIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),NewActivity.class);
         String myText = "this is the text";
         newActIntent.putExtra("TextViewContent",mText);
         startActivity(newActIntent);
       }
     });        
    }

}

public class NewActivity extends Activity {

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanteState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   String stringContent = intent.getStringExtra("TextViewContent");
   setContentView(R.layout.your_new_activity);
   TextView textview = ( TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView);
   textview.setText(stringContent);

  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The code you are using is wrong because you can't use `findViewById` to get a View that is not in the current layout.

You could do the following:

- In the first Activity `onClick` method, after creating the Intent put the text you want in an extra:

  `newActIntent.putExtra("name", "some text");`
- In the onCreate method of the second Activity:

  `TextView tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView);
  String myText= getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
  tView.setText(myText);`

**EDIT**

You have 2 Activities:

**Activity A** I suppose the code you've posted corresponds to this Activity. It will be:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TextView tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView);


            Intent newActIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),NewActivity.class);
            String myText = "this is the text";
            newActIntent.putExtra("name", myText);   // Adding the extra
            startActivity(newActIntent);

        }
    });
}
```

**Activity B**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

    TextView tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView);
    String myText = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");  // Retrieving the extra
    tView.setText(myText);

    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But can you please explain further?

Comment: i added another button to the first intent to display a different text on the same page. depending o which button is clicked but the first button is showing no text when i press it. just the secon is working. can you help me with this?

Comment: In the code `newActIntent.putExtra("name", myText);` at first Activity "name" must be the same for the 2 buttons. Also be sure that the intent is the same. Does it always happen when press the second button? If still not working please post the code for the 2 buttons.

Comment: i just figured it out. i added and additional textview to my layout. thanks, i appreciate your help.